# If op-amp offset trims are provided, but not needed, what is the best practise for connecting them?

Tags: operational-amplifier, offset

I'm using op-amps with offset trims available, but not needed as they already have very low offset voltage. What is the best practise for the PCB pad connections - should they simply be left floating?

(I'm beginning to realise how much my degree left out)

Comment: Yes, leave them floating if you do not need offset compensation. This is true for most opamps. However, the datasheet will be leading so read it ! The degree is only there for you to realise how much you do not know ;-) But also to understand the basics and how to acquire the knowledge you do need.

Comment: Your comment has inspired me to study less /s
Seriously though, that's a pretty interesting way to look at it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If nothing is said** about it in the data sheet and application notes (as does occur sometimes), **leave them floating**.

If there is direction in the data sheet or application notes, follow it precisely, as @IC_designer_Rimpelbekkie says. I can't recall any exceptions, but that doesn't mean that there are not one or two types of op-amps somewhere that require you to do something different.

In any case, keep the traces (if any) to the offset null pins short and symmetrical- the offset pins are generally connected directly to the long tailed pair and have the potential to pick up noise.

A general comment inspired by the terminology you used - it is not a good idea to use the offset null adjustment for "trimming" offset to a non-zero value. Any adjustment so made will tend to degrade the temperature coefficient of the amplifier (usually something like PTAT (proportional to absolute temperature)). If you need (say) a 2mV offset it's usually best to create it with a stable reference voltage rather than deliberately unbalancing a balanced circuit.